# Why is `wp_unschedule_event` not working

Tags: wp-cron

I have following code. `wp_clear_scheduled_hook` and `wp_unschedule_hook` are working when uncomment them. But `wp_unschdule_event` is not working. Why?

```
public function __construct() {
    register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'cron_activation' ) );
    register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'cron_deactivation' ) );
    add_action( 'cron_schedules', array( $this, 'cron_schedules' ) );
    add_action( 'lrn_wp_cron', array( $this, 'cron_action' ) );
}

public function cron_activation() {
    if (! wp_next_scheduled('lrn_wp_cron')) {
        wp_schedule_event( time() + WEEK_IN_SECONDS, 'lrn_wp_weekly', 'lrn_wp_cron', array( 'hello.php' ) );
        wp_schedule_event( time() + MONTH_IN_SECONDS, 'lrn_wp_monthly', 'lrn_wp_cron', array( 'akismet/akismet.php' ) );
    }
}

public function cron_deactivation() {
    $timestamp = wp_next_scheduled('lrn_wp_cron');
    wp_unschedule_event($timestamp, 'lrn_wp_cron', array( 'hello.php' ) );
    wp_unschedule_event($timestamp, 'lrn_wp_cron', array( 'akismet/akismet.php' ) );
    // wp_clear_scheduled_hook('lrn_wp_cron', array('hello.php'));
    // wp_clear_scheduled_hook('lrn_wp_cron', array('akismet/akismet.php'));
    // wp_unschedule_hook('lrn_wp_cron');
}
```

Comment: It works when I have `args()` Optional? argument like
`wp_next_scheduled('lrn_wp_cron', array('hello.php');`

Comment: It turns out that, I can only unschedule_event by exactly matching args when schedule event. In other words, 2nd parameter is optional, only when you have used 2nd parameter when scheduling the event. 

All `wp_schedule_event` and `wp_next_scheduled` and `wp_unschedule_event` args parameter should match each other.

Comment: you can use this plugin to debug the cron jobs : https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/